# Calling union member in struct with c

Tags: c, struct

Below is piece of code which I am working on..

```
struct ArgusRecord {
   struct ArgusRecordHeader hdr;
   union {
      struct ArgusMarStruct     mar;
      struct ArgusMarSupStruct  sup;
      struct ArgusFarStruct     far;
      struct ArgusEventStruct event;
#if defined ARGUS_PLURIBUS
      struct ArgusVflowStruct vflow;
#endif
   } ar_un;
};
```

I have defined my variable as

```
struct ArgusRecord MyRecord;
```

I can call the first member `MyRecord.hdr` If same way I call the union members such as `mar`, `sup` .. etc I am getting the error message `..... has no member named ‘mar’`

Please some one tell me how to call the union members.

Comment: access union members as `MyRecord.ar_un.<union members>`

Answer (score 3):

You have to call using the `union` name `ar_un`

```
MyRecord.ar_un.mar
```

Answer (score 1):

Members of unions are accessed with dot notation.
In other words, `mar` must be accessed like this:

```
struct ArgusRecord record;
record.ar_un.mar (...)
```